# getting source not found on setContentView

Tags: android

I am getting an  source not found  on  setContentView in this line:

```
  setContentView(R.layout.webview);
```

On onItemClick action.
I have 2 xml files.
One is an list items. its look like that:

list_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="15sp" >
</TextView>
```

I am trying to do when the user click on the item on the list it will just load it.
my xml of it is:
webview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

here the full code of it.its all works great till setContentView:

```
public class NewsActivity  extends ListActivity {
WebView mWebView;
 public ReadXML ReadXML=new ReadXML();
 public  ArrayList<String> ynetList =new ArrayList<String>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

for(int i=0;i<ReadXML.hadashotListItems.size();i++)
   ynetList.add(ReadXML.hadashotListItems.get(i).title+"\n"+ReadXML.hadashotListItems.get(i).pubDate);

      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, ynetList));

      View v=getListView() ;

      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        String s=   ReadXML.hadashotListItems.get(position).link;

        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(s);



        }
      }
      );
    }}
```

Answer (score 3):

A `ListActivity` needs a `ListView` with the ID `android.R.id.list`. As you create your activity, everything is fine because you're not specifying a content view of your own, and so a default content view containing just a list is being used.

Now, in your `setContentView` call, what your code is really saying is "Now I want the entire screen to be a big webview." In doing this, you're violating the `ListActivity` requirement of always having a `ListView`.

You *could* create a layout file that contains a `WebView` *and* a `ListView` with the ID `android.R.id.list`, and use onclick to toggle their visibility, and perhaps listen to the hardware back button to toggle back. But I think it would be a neater approach to simply have the click listener launch a new activity, containing only the `WebView`:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
       String s = ReadXML.hadashotListItems.get(position).link;

       Intent intent = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("url", s);

       startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

You could then let your new `WebActivity` class set `R.layout.webview` as its content view. Pressing the hardware back button will automatically finish that activity, and bring you back to the list, where you were.

Comment: I am a little confused. Can you give me the code that can solve that.

Comment: `public class NewsActivity  extends Activity`

Comment: @Vitaly: Hmm, I realize I might have misunderstood what you were trying to do before, but the general problem is still the same (missing a ListView). I've updated my answer to better reflect what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I did what you said but get error source not found on:Intent intent = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, WebActivity.class); I created a class public class WebActivity extends Activity {  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);  
        WebView wv;  
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);  
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");  
    }  
}

Answer (score 1):

don't you want to create a new activity that loads your url more than changing the whole layout of your current activity ? It seems ackward.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: I did anther  action but get source not found look my comment to David Hedlund. maybe you can help with that. also I added <activity android:name=" com.example.News.WebActivity" /> but still get that error